QGIS: display a common graduated style based on a common attribute column of all layers
QGIS: I have several layers which contain the same attribute with different values (for example attribute X). I want to display a common graduated style based on the common attribute column of all layers. The ranges should be generated according to the values of this X column across all the layers.
Any ideas?

combine them into a single layer and symbolize it once

How would I do that?
